# Can a custom GetHashcode implementation cause problems with Dictionary or Hashtable's "buckets"

Tags: c#, dictionary, gethashcode, compareto, sorteddictionary

I'm considering implementing  my own custom hashcode for a given object... and use this as a `key` for my dictionary.  Since it's possible (likely) that 2 objects will have the same hashcode, what additional operators should I override, and what should that override (conceptually) look like?

```
   myDictionary.Add(myObj.GetHashCode(),myObj);
```

vs

```
   myDictionary.Add(myObj,myObj);
```

In other words, does a Dictionary use a combination of the following in order to determine uniqueness and which bucket to place an object in?

Which are more important than others?

- HashCode
- Equals
- ==
- CompareTo()

Is compareTo only needed in the SortedDictionary?

Answer (score 2):

What is GetHashCode used for?

It is by design useful for only one thing: putting an object in a hash table. Hence the name.

GetHashCode is designed to do only one thing: balance a hash table. Do not use it for anything else. In particular:

- It does not provide a unique key for an object; probability of collision is extremely high.
- It is not of cryptographic strength, so do not use it as part of a digital signature or as a password equivalent
- It does not necessarily have the error-detection properties needed for checksums.

and so on.

Eric Lippert

http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

Answer (score 1):

It's not the buckets that cause the problem - it is actually finding the right object instance once you have determined the bucket using the hash code. Since all objects in a bucket share the same hash code, object equality (`Equals`) is used to find the right one. The rule is that if two objects are considered equal, they should produce the same hash code - but two objects producing the same hash codes might not be equal.